# getting data using BufferedInputStream

Tags: java

I am trying to monitor apache server through http. The code i am using is shown below.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
byte[] outputBuffer = new byte[8192];
int bytesRead = 0;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

try {
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(sourceUrl.openStream());
    while (true) {
    bytesRead = bis.read(buffer);
        if (bytesRead == -1)
            break;

        baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    bis.close();
    outputBuffer = baos.toByteArray();
    baos.close();

    return outputBuffer;
}catch{}
```

I expecting the values as name-value pair. But some times I am getting as shown below

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
  <html>
    <head>
      <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=LoginAction.action">
      </head>
      <body>
        <p>Loading ...</p>
      </body>
  </html>
```

why is it happening. what should I do in code to get proper values? Please help

Comment: Where do you expect name value pairs? Also `Learn Me Java` should be `Teach Me Java`.

Answer (score 0):

The line `<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=LoginAction.action">`
says that the user agent (aka browser) shall refresh the page by loading the relative URL `LoginAction.action`. So your problem is at the server/session state, not in the code that reads from the stream.

By the way, your use of `BufferedInputStream` is completely obsolete. You can read directly from the `InputStream` returned by `URL.openStream()`.

Further, `byte[] outputBuffer = new byte[8192];` is nonsense. You are never using the array you create here as you overwrite the value of this variable with the result of `baos.toByteArray()`. Just declaring the variable `byte[] outputBuffer;` is enough.

Comment: I am able to get expected details with some of the apache server. But on particular server I am getting this problem. So how will i proceed. What is this LoginAction.action. Where can i find this URL.
Now i am using http://10.2.0.162/server-status?auto. On changing the URL can i get the expected result. similary like
http://10.2.0.162/LoginAction.action

Comment: I can’t tell you anything about *your* server. But resolving a relative URL indeed works this way. If you base URL is `server/pathTo/file` the resolved URL is `server/pathTo/login.action`. And `pathTo/` might be empty as in your example. The class [`URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) provides the [resolve](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#resolve(java.lang.String)) algorithm.